# Unity - How to make a dropdown list like the one in the Project window

Tags: c#, window, editor, dropdown, unity-game-engine

I'm currently trying to make a dropdown list similar to the one you'll find in the project window. I've found a "Unity Manual" page for such a thing but it doesn't go into how to actually make it. Here is the page: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Dropdown.html

A picture for reference:

[image]

If you could help me out with this it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

are you using any framwork, you can try to accomplish this using bootstrap dropdown classes so you can create menu with subs and declare subs directions example left, right, down as you please.

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html

i used this  link to combine for my needs, hope it helps